# Why does this date not print in the correct time zone?

Tags: c#, timezone-offset

I am attempting to print (to screen) a datetimeoffset in a user-defined time zone. However, it seems that the "TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc" function actually changes the time object, and the "ToString" function always reverts to the system time zone. Here is my code:

```
var myDate = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2023-08-18T12:39:00.000-0800"); // date input as PST
TimeZoneInfo tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Greenwich Standard Time");
DateTime printableTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(myDate.UtcDateTime, tzi); // converting to UDT per customer's request
logger.LogInformation(printableTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:sszzz")); // (attempt to) output in UDT
```

It actually changes the time, and then prints that time in CST (my system time zone):

**2023-08-18 20:39:00-05:00**

Am I not understanding how `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc` works? I thought it just changed the time zone of the DateTime object. What am I missing here? What do I need to do to make the "ToString" function simply print the original DateTime object in the "Greenwich Standard Time" time zone, like this:

**2023-08-18 20:39:00+00:00**

*Edit: I cannot simply use `model.DateFrom.UtcDateTime` to get the UDT date, as this is customer defined. They selected UDT in this example, but they may also select something else, such as "Eastern Standard Time" or "Myanmar Standard Time", etc.

Comment: What is `model.DateFrom.UtcDateTime` and you haven't used `myDate` anywhere?

Comment: Hi @phuzi, you are right, I was changing that for the purposes of this post. In my original code it is model.DateFrom.UtcDateTime. I changed it to myDate to make it easier to read. It is updated in the post now.

Comment: `2023-08-18T12:39:00.000-0800` does not have a timezone.  It has an offset, which is distinctly different

Comment: "I thought it just changed the time zone of the DateTime object". DateTime does not know anything about timezones it just distincts local and Utc. So in this case ToString uses local timezone(your systems timezone).

Comment: @GuruStron, as stated in the post, I cannot do that because the time zone is user-defined. I am using Greenwich Standard Time in this example, but the user may also select something else, such as "Eastern Standard Time" or "Myanmar Standard Time", etc.

Comment: @Ralf, correct. `DateTime` does not. But `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc` does.

Comment: @possum, correct, that string does not have a time zone. That is why I am converting it to UDT, and then using `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc`.

Comment: `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc` results in `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` which it seems to affect things.

Comment: @MattSpinks there's certainly misunderstanding. There's no `UDT`.  `12:39-08:00` *is* `20:39+00:00` so `myDate.UtcDateTime` already gives you the UTC time. Calling `ConvertTimeFromUtc` does nothing more that strip the `DateTimeKind.Utc` indication, so `ToString` behaves the same way as if you'd asked to format a local time. By that time any offset information is lost, so `zzz` can only print the local offset

Comment: Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos. I was definitely mis-understanding how `ConvertTimeFromUtc` worked. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using [`TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.converttime?view=net-7.0#system-timezoneinfo-converttime(system-datetimeoffset-system-timezoneinfo)):

> Converts a time to the time in a particular time zone.

```
DateTimeOffset printableTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(myDate, tzi);
Console.WriteLine(printableTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:sszzz"));
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Something seems to be lost when using `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc`. But using `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime` maintains the time zone when using `ToString`.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the offset of the desired time zone and add it back to a new `DateTimeOffset` object.

Here is an example.

```
var myDate = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2023-08-18T12:39:03.723-0800"); // date input as PST
TimeZoneInfo tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
DateTime printableTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(myDate.UtcDateTime, tzi); // converting to UDT per customer's request
Console.WriteLine(printableTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:sszzz")); // (attempt to) output in UDT

TimeSpan offset = tzi.GetUtcOffset(printableTime);
DateTimeOffset dateTimeOffset = new DateTimeOffset(printableTime, offset);
Console.WriteLine(dateTimeOffset.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:sszzz")); // Outputs the current date and time with the selected time zone offset
```